# How to create stacked bar chart with given dataframe shape?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe and would like to create a stacked bar chart by having date on the x-axis and quantity on the y-axis. This is the current dataframe:

```
date       | product_group | quantity
2021-10-01 | A             | 10
2021-10-01 | C             | 10
2021-10-01 | Z             | 80
2021-11-11 | A             | 13
2021-12-12 | B             | 5..
```

I am trying to get to this output using either matplotlib or seaborn where I have:

- quantity on the x-axis (% stack)
- date on the y-axis
- have quantity stacked for each unique date & product group option. I.e. for date 10-01, we have a stack with A,C,Z and their respective quantities (relative to each other, i.e. A=0.1, C=0.1, Z=0.8)

What is the best approach here? Any advise is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a one-liner with [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html):

```
sns.histplot(df, y='date', weights='quantity', hue='product_group', multiple='stack')
```

Output:
[image]

Edit: if you want all bars to have the same length, set `multiple` to `fill`:

```
sns.histplot(df, y='date', weights='quantity', hue='product_group', multiple='fill')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this is amazing. Is there a way to display this at 100% stack rather?

Comment: If you want all bars to be at 100%, change to `multiple='fill'`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use seaborn but rather matplotlib, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2021-10-01']*3 + ['2021-11-11', '2021-11-12'],
    'product_group': ['A', 'C', 'Z', 'A', 'B'],
    'quantity': [10,10,80,13,5]
})

# pivot values into columns for stacked plot
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='product_group', values='quantity')

# create percentages
df.div(df.sum(axis=1),axis=0).plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work unfortunately because I have dates that are dupliates, so it throws a duplicate index error. Can this is worked around?

Comment: I dont understand. In my df there are also multiple times `2021-10-01`. I am guessing you dont have unique date+product_group combinations. For that purpose you could `df.groupby(['date', 'product_group'])` and then aggregate your values, e.g. by summing.